# How far away would a supernucleus comet be visible?

Tags: orbit, comets

If an instrument like LSST quickly spots something as soon as it reaches magnitude 24½, how far away would a 60km first-time visitor from the Oort cloud be when it is spotted? I'm thinking that a huge iceball will make a visible coma sooner, but have no idea what actual numbers would be.

And, given that distance and a parabolic orbit, how much time would that give before it crosses Earth's orbit?

Comment: Question #2,000, if anyone's interested.

Answer (score 2):

> Even 100 meter NEOs could cause significant damage, and there are far
>   more of them. LSST will be able to detect objects as faint as 24.5 in
>   magnitude in a 30s visit, enabling it to detect 140m NEOs **[as far away
>   as the Main Belt asteroids.](http://www.lsst.org/lsst/science/scientist_solar_system)**
>   [...] During its survey of the sky, LSST can find 90% of the PHAs over
>   140 meters in diameter.

Earth is 1 AU from the Sun, so [that would be](http://space-facts.com/asteroid-belt/) **1.2 to 2.2 AU away from us:**

> The Asteroid Belt is located in an area of space between the orbits of
>   Mars and Jupiter. That places it between 2.2 and 3.2 astronomical
>   units (AU) from the Sun. The belt is about 1 AU thick. The average
>   distance between objects in the Asteroid Belt is quite large. If you
>   could stand on an asteroid and look around, the next one would be too
>   far away to see very well.

Timewise, it would be [about 8 years away:](http://www.lsst.org/lsst/sites/default/files/NEOwarning-1.pdf)

> The bottom right panel shows an example of a very different hazardous object - the 3 km large comet C/1996 B2 Hyakutake, which passed within 0.10 AU from Earth
>   in 1996. The apparent magnitude vs. distance diagram indicates that the current
>   generation of wide-angle imaging surveys, such as SDSS with V < 22,
>   could have provided an early warning about 3 years before the closest
>   approach (if they had sufficient cadence and sky coverage). **With LSST,
>   the warning time would be ∼8 years**, with over 500 observations over
>   that period.

Fortunately, your comet is 60 km, making the [comet tail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_tail) easy to spot:

> While the solid nucleus of comets is generally less than 50 km across,
>   the coma may be larger than the Sun, and **ion tails have been observed
>   to extend 3.8 astronomical units** (570 Gm; 350×106 mi).

[This table of impact risks](http://neo.jpl.nasa.gov/risks/) shows that the most likely (5.8e-02) impact is between 2095 and 2113.